# dir=auto attribute is not working when applied to paragraph tag

Tags: html, css

HTML tag dir="auto" is not working
 I have Urdu content it correctly going in the first line from right to left but not correctly going in the second line.
In the second line, it is going from left to right 
I have this in a paragraph tag

```html
<p dir="auto">دوسری جانب ڈونلڈ ٹرمپ نے کسی غیر قانونی اقدام کی تردید کرتے ہوئے ان کوششوں کو ’وِچ ہنٹ‘ یا ایذارسانی قرار دیا ہے۔ </p>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you set a `lang` attribute?

Comment: Yes I have but still, it is not working I have put lang attribute in HTML tag <html lang="ur">

Comment: Unable to replicate - see the snippet.

Comment: In the snippet, it is working but not on my website please see the screenshot

Comment: If you can't replicate it HERE...we can't help.

Comment: @Paulie_D please have a look on this http://www.islamicmediaservice.com/viewBlogDetail?id=110 see the title of blog